# Momentum and its Expectation value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum

I was being interviewed by XYZ, and was asked to prove that expectation value of momentum for a potential V=V(x) is zero when the potential is symmetric.

According to my knowledge expectation value of momentum is always 0 irrespective of potential being symmetric or not.

Comment: Don't you rather mean the expectation value of a symmetric wave function: $\psi(r)=\psi(-r)$? Or perhaps the energy eigenstate of $H=p^2/2+V$? As stated, your question does not make much sense, you need to precise the ket/ensemble with which you want to calculate the expectation value.